# How to configure Apache to serve Drupal 6 Multisite configuration

Tags: apache, drupal, drupal-6

I am trying to setup Apache to serve a Drupal 6 multi-site configuration, but I cannot seem to get it properly set up.

**In my httpd.conf**:

```
DocumentRoot "/Users/kevinyoung/Sites/drupal"

<Directory "/Users/kevinyoung/Sites/drupal">
    Options FollowSymLinks Multiviews Indexes
    MultiviewsMatch Any
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
```

**In httpd-vhosts.conf**:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/kevinyoung/Sites/drupal"
    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/error_log"
    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/access_log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName drupal.local
    ServerAlias *.drupal.local
    DocumentRoot /Users/kevinyoung/Sites/drupal
    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/error_log"
    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

**In /etc/hosts**:

```
127.0.0.1       drupal.local
127.0.0.1       <site_name>.drupal.local
```

Navigating to http://localhost shows "It Works!".
Navigating to drupal.local takes me to the default site for my D6 multi-site setup.

Now lets say I have another site directory (site_A.drupal.local) as another site inside drupal/sites/. Now I go to site_A.drupal.local, but it still takes me to the default site. Why would this be happening?

Any ideas why I can't access any other site besides my default site in this Drupal 6 multi-site configuration?

I am running Apache 2.4 on Mac OSX 10.10 Yosemite with Drupal 6, mysql 5.1.73, and php 5.5.14.

Comment: It *kind of* looks like you're trying to set up subdomains. Is this right?

Comment: Yeah. Drupal 6 multi-site configuration is supposed to take these subdomains on drupal.local and map them to the appropriate site directory in drupal/sites/, but its not happening and I can't seem to figure out why.